# google analytics enhanced ecommerce action not linked?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I add **Enhanced Ecommerce** in my GA tracking, all steps tracking fine, except **CheckOut** to **Transaction**, two action not linked together **(has checkout but shows 0%)**.

P.S. I user third Third-Party Payment and in my test enviroment, staging GA，two action links OK. So I think maybe I miss some GA setting?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related and may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that you have not added the third party payment gateway to your referral exclusion list. Therefore, every time a user returns to your site after paying, this is triggering a new session in GA (with a new source/medium). This is why you see 1 session with transactions but 0% funnel carry through. Try adding the domain of your payment gateway by following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).